# How to fetch nested object based on key value using mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a record of following format...

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("609cd99d1af4ac1036d78f7d"),
"userrole" : "admins",
"locks" : [
{
"userid" : "2932fb99-4c41-4342-99e0-af15f8146da0",
"useremail" : "fsasdev@gmail.com",
"filepath" : "output/notes.txt",
.
.
}
]
}
```

How to fetch userid,useremail where filepath matches"output/notes.txt"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Demo - https://mongoplayground.net/p/FFYYCqOmPx-

Use [$](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/projection/positional/)

> The positional $ operator limits the contents of a  to return the **first** element that matches the query condition on the array.

```
db.collection.find({
  "locks.filepath": "output/notes.txt" // query 
},
{
  "locks.$": 1 // projection
})
```

---

Demo - https://mongoplayground.net/p/TLqmuhN6H3q

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: { "locks.filepath": "output/notes.txt" } // filter to reduce load in unwind
  },
  { $unwind: "$locks" }, //  break into individual documents
  {
    $match: { "locks.filepath": "output/notes.txt" } // filter
  },
  {
    $replaceRoot: { "newRoot": "$locks" } // set root as $locks
  }
])
```

Comment: I want to fetch only details of that particular object , how can i achieve that?

Comment: @sd updated answer

Comment: This works very well, Thank you so much for the quick answer. can you also please tell me why you have used $match twice? it works if i use it only once

Comment: with huge dataset unwind will run all documents, we want to reduce that to make query faster, so we are filtering records 1st to make sure we get fewer records for unwinding.